# How to get rid of a standard user in my accounts on Mac?

Tags: accounts

I added another user to my Mac and then didn't know how to fill out all the technical questions. The problem is I cannot use my trackpad when the computer starts. I have to use a mouse.

I would like to get rid of this standard user, or somehow figure out the answers to my questions on filling out the standard user form in hopes the trackpad problem will go away. Or have I somehow lost my trackpad functionality in the opening screen of the computer forever?

Comment: It is unlikely that adding a new user will cause the trackpad to start working again.  Does the trackpad work after you log in?

Comment: yes it does. It is only the initial logging in! and ...it neither works for either of the names given. I must use a mouse

Comment: actually it is not my question to add a new user. The question is how to get rid of the new user I just added

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot use my trackpad"?  Does the mouse cursor not move?  Or does it move and you are just unable to click?

Comment: the track pad does not respond to my fingers, meaning there is no entrance into my giving my pass word. Or even clicking on which user I want. I am forced to use a mouse. Also when I tried to go into preferences to subtract the user, this was impossible" the minus sign was not available to me

Comment: see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences > Users & Groups

select the user in the list on the left.  Click the minus sign at the bottom of the list.

If the preference pane is locked (see lock icon and text in lower left corner) you will need to unlock the pane before you can make changes.